# Non parametric cointegration test in R

Tags: r, nonparametric, cointegration

I am not very comfortable with the (parametric) assumptions made in cointegration analysis. I have recently found that there is a way to carry out nonparametric conintegration analysis (a google search with the term 'nonparametric cointegration' yields several results).

Is anyone aware of an R package that allows for nonparametric cointegration analysis?

Comment: Perhaps of some interest: [Link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urca/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question is quite old, but ranks pretty high on Google search.
A good library with plenty of non-parametric or semi-parametric test for cointegration is [LongMemoryTS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LongMemoryTS/index.html). Full documentation of its function is here in its [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LongMemoryTS/LongMemoryTS.pdf).